# Ежедневный буфер активности

Tags: php, mysql, json, base64

Нужен совет. Совсем скоро планирую добавить на сайт модуль по сбору информации о активности пользователя и подсчёта этой активности. Коротко о самом модуле: данный модуль собирает все сведения о активности пользователя в ежедневный буфер (в текущей версии всё данные записываются в БД), а через сутки выполняется подсчёт этой самой активности и выдача награды пользователю. И стал передо мной такой вопрос: а как же правильно собирать информацию? Ведь это слишком много запросов в БД. Как вариант записывать всё в json каждый день, и все шифровать в base64. Но будет ли это лучше? Или есть ещё какая-либо альтернатива?

Comment: Вот бы ещё понять, что такое "активность пользователя"... главное - не планируйте добавлять ещё и модуль сбора информации о пассивности, побьют...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ведь это слишком много запросов в БД.

если у вас небольшое кол-во пользователей (не сайт-миллионик), то обычная БД это переварит ( ну 100 - 1000 запросов в секунду во всяком случае переварить сможет)

> Как вариант записывать всё в json каждый день

где именно? хранить на стороне пользователя json?

> и все шифровать в base64.

при передаче json на сервер вам по идее и так это придётся делать

> Но будет ли это лучше? Или есть ещё какая-либо альтернатива?

смотря что вы понимаете под **активностью** пользователя, насколько эта активность активна и как много пользователь работает с сайтом:

1. если под активностью пользователя понимать, на какую страницу заходит пользователь и какой элемент пользователь нажимает - то это относительно редкие вещи, поэтому можно сразу посылать их на сервер и записывать в БД, причем таблицу можно организовать совсем просто:

   идентификатор пользователя | тип действия | объект действия | время действия | дополнительная информация
2. в продолжении п.1) если действий относительно много, то их можно накапливать на клиенте пользователя и отсылать раз в минуту или при накоплении 100 действий, сами действия хранить в массиве со структурой описанной выше - по сути это будет json-данные, которые вы потом превращаете в строку (base64) и пересылаете на сервер
3. если же под действиями понимается любой чих - сколько раз пользователь нажал клавишу или кнопку мыши, сколько километров пробегал курсором мышки, какой текст вводил, с какой интенсивностью и т.д., то это опять таки надо будет накапливать на клиенте и пересылать порциями, причем желательно поджимать информацию тогда - к примеру те же числа (если их много) передавать не в 10ричной системе исчисления, а в 256ричной, типа не `20`, а `' '`

Comment: 1. Да на стороне пользователя. Под активностью я имел ввиду написание сообщений, добавление фото и т.п. Благодарю за ответ, буду тогда записывать в БД